# Redmine can't send email in daemon mode

Tags: email, unix, redmine, webrick, pony

I'm using Redmine 2.5.2 on Debian with webrick and Pony gem for sending e-mails.

When I run webrick in common mode (with -e), it sends fine. But when I'm running it in daemon mode (with -d) it falls with HTTP 500 error (and nothing is mentioned in production.log).

What can it be? I think, the problem is with user rights. Is there any limitations in Debian for daemons to access the SMTP servers?

Comment: (1) Redmine doesn't use pony anywhere but uses ActionMailer. This is configured in `config/configuration.yml`. I don't know where pony comes into play here... (2) The SMTP server is not restricted. However, you probably start Redmine in the wrong environment (it defaults to development) which thus uses another set of configuration options. Ensure that you start Redmine in production mode.

Comment: I'm actually writing a plugin for Redmine. I use Pony to send emails from it.

Comment: The only difference in config is that I'm running -e production vs -d production